# Store items in array with using them later

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I have code, which get json file from server and then render some if its elements on the page.  In this code i also skip items with duplicate value of key "points". My question is, how do i make these skipped items to store somewhere, so if i click on item that has duplicate, it would link me to some other page with list of these duplicates?
Here is my code

```
var request = $.ajax({
type: "GET",
    url: "example.com/rewards.json"
    dataType: "json",
    error: function (data, textStatus){
         console.log( "it`s error" );
             console.log( status );
         console.log( data );},
        success: function (data, textStatus){
        console.log( "success" );
        console.log( status );
        console.log( data );
         }
        })
        request.success(function(data, textStatus){
            var lis = "";
            var arr = [];
            var iter = 0;

            $.each(data.rewards, function(key, val){
                if ($.inArray(val.points, arr) == -1)
                    {
                        lis += "<div class = 'ui-block-" + String.fromCharCode(97 + iter%3) + "'><a href ='#' class ='ui-link-inherit'>" + val.points + "</a></div>";
                        arr.push(val.points);
                        iter +=  1;
                    }
            });
            $("#rewards_table").html(lis);
        })
```

Description of what i want might be a little confusable, so feel free to ask me anything

Comment: do you want something which will keep your array for future use?

Comment: I think a concrete example would help. That is, show some exampledata, e.g. the structure, plus what you would how the 'other page' would look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just do exactly that: Store them somewhere for use later.

For example, put this line at the top of your code:

```
var duplicates = [];
```

...and add this `else` to the `if` inside your `$.each` iterator function:

```
else
   {
   duplicates.push(val.points);
   }
```

*(I* think *I got your bracing style right there, a bit alien to me. :-) )*

The above assumes all of your code is held in some kind of containing function, to avoid creating globals, and so `duplicates` (like your existing `request` variable) won't end up becoming a global.

Comment: I dont exactly understand how can i link new array with rendered duplicate item. And do i need to have new array for each duplicated item?

Comment: @sannySin: In your existing code, you're "linking" them based on the value of `val.points`. So if you have a rendered element with a given `val.points` value (the text of your `a` element), and there's a matching `val.points` value in `duplicates`, that links them. No, you wouldn't want a different array for each duplicated item, just one array containing them all. If you need other information from `val`, store `val` rather than `val.points` and then search through the array with `$.each` rather than `$.inArray` (comparing the `points` value you have with the `points` property of each entry).